# signal strength adhoc mode ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Are there any possible ways to measure signal strength while two ubuntu machines are running in ad hoc mode. I have tried with iwspy command but it shows me error as follows.

root@dibya-notebook:~/Desktop# iwspy wlan0
wlan0     Interface doesn't support wireless statistic collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@dibya-notebook:~/Desktop# iwspy wlan0 wlan0 Interface doesn't support wireless
statistic collection
```

The above error is because your `iwspy` is not activated on your interface. If I remember correctly you can activate it specifying target `IP` address and `NIC` interface as,

```
sudo iwspy wlan0 <IP addr>
```

Also you can de-activate it by `sudo iwspy wlan0 off`.